# Specific fields from macOS Command "diskutil apfs list"

Tags: bash, shell-script, osx

would appreciate inputs on the subject. I have the output from the macOS (*High Sierra;FileSystem :APFS*)  command - `diskutil apfs list`. Sample output is given below:

```
+-- Container disk5 1B5FE22B-6F4F-4EB9-8AA3-D326E4E940DF
|   ====================================================
|   APFS Container Reference:     disk5
|   Size (Capacity Ceiling):      250140434432 B (250.1 GB)
|   Minimum Size:                 192333017088 B (192.3 GB)
|   Capacity In Use By Volumes:   186220453888 B (186.2 GB) (74.4% used)
|   Capacity Not Allocated:       63919980544 B (63.9 GB) (25.6% free)
|   |
|   +-< Physical Store disk4s2 E6FF882B-995C-4C60-B164-76923667F8A1
|   |   -----------------------------------------------------------
|   |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk4s2
|   |   Size:                       250140434432 B (250.1 GB)
|   |
|   +-> Volume disk5s1 7BB363F8-A658-4B6C-A4B4-778AC782785E
|   |   ---------------------------------------------------
|   |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk5s1 (No specific role)
|   |   Name:                      Macintosh HD (Case-insensitive)
|   |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
|   |   Capacity Consumed:         181760897024 B (181.8 GB)
|   |   FileVault:                 Yes (Locked)
|   |
|   +-> Volume disk5s2 48A79DA5-1228-4F5A-8851-5178B91D2310
|   |   ---------------------------------------------------
|   |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk5s2 (Preboot)
|   |   Name:                      Preboot (Case-insensitive)
|   |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
|   |   Capacity Consumed:         66613248 B (66.6 MB)
|   |   FileVault:                 No
|   |
|   +-> Volume disk5s3 D46C3FA0-5B9D-4E13-9327-EEFB483F692E
|   |   ---------------------------------------------------
|   |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk5s3 (Recovery)
|   |   Name:                      Recovery (Case-insensitive)
|   |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
|   |   Capacity Consumed:         1033371648 B (1.0 GB)
|   |   FileVault:                 No
|   |
|   +-> Volume disk5s4 3E852266-E0C3-48AB-ACAD-D73CEE0134F1
|       ---------------------------------------------------
|       APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk5s4 (VM)
|       Name:                      VM (Case-insensitive)
|       Mount Point:               Not Mounted
|       Capacity Consumed:         3221250048 B (3.2 GB)
|       FileVault:                 No
```

My objective was:

1. Output disk container along with GUID for fileVault status of "Yes (Locked)" .
2. Store the GUID for fileVault status of "Yes (Locked)"  into a variable.

I came up with the following:

```
diskutil apfs list|awk '/[A-Z0-9]{8}-([A-Z0-9]{4}-){3}[A-Z0-9]{12}$|.l/{print}'
```

Output:

```
+-- Container disk5 1B5FE22B-6F4F-4EB9-8AA3-D326E4E940DF
|   Size (Capacity Ceiling):      250140434432 B (250.1 GB)
|   Capacity In Use By Volumes:   186220453888 B (186.2 GB) (74.4% used)
|   Capacity Not Allocated:       63919980544 B (63.9 GB) (25.6% free)
|   +-< Physical Store disk4s2 E6FF882B-995C-4C60-B164-76923667F8A1
|   |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk4s2
|   +-> Volume disk5s1 7BB363F8-A658-4B6C-A4B4-778AC782785E
|   |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk5s1 (No specific role)
|   |   FileVault:                 Yes (Locked)
|   +-> Volume disk5s2 48A79DA5-1228-4F5A-8851-5178B91D2310
|   |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk5s2 (Preboot)
|   |   FileVault:                 No
|   +-> Volume disk5s3 D46C3FA0-5B9D-4E13-9327-EEFB483F692E
|   |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk5s3 (Recovery)
|   |   FileVault:                 No
|   +-> Volume disk5s4 3E852266-E0C3-48AB-ACAD-D73CEE0134F1
|       APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk5s4 (VM)
|       FileVault:                 No
```

Any inputs to correct/modify the code are welcome :).
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't have a Mac, but I think it may be easier and more robust to give diskutil the `-plist` option, then use `plutil` to either extract the fields you want or convert the plist into xml or json format, after which you can use `xmlstarlet` or `jq` to extract the fields you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going with [Mark Plotnick's suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/507217/specific-fields-from-macos-command-diskutil-apfs-list#comment936834_507217) of converting the structured XML output of

```
diskutil apfs list -plist
```

into JSON and parsing it with `jq`.  The `jq` utility is available from Homebrew on macOS.

This has to be done in two steps as the `plutil` needs to read a regular file:

```
diskutil apfs list -plist >list.xml
plutil -convert json -o list.json list.xml
```

From the generated JSON file, we may extract the APFS volume UUID of all volumes that have FileVault enabled and that are locked, using

```
jq -r '.Containers[].Volumes[] | select(.FileVault == true and .Locked == true) | .APFSVolumeUUID' list.json
```

Assigning this to a variable, in one "single" command:

```
locked_uuids=$(
    diskutil apfs list -plist >list.xml
    plutil -convert json -o list.json list.xml
    jq -r '.Containers[].Volumes[] | select(.FileVault == true and .Locked == true) | .APFSVolumeUUID' list.json
    rm -f list.xml list.json
)
```

Note that the above command overwrites and removes the two files `list.xml` and `list.json` in the current directory.  You may want to create temporary files using `mktemp` instead:

```
locked_uuids=$(
    tmpxml=$(mktemp)
    tmpjson=$(mktemp)
    diskutil apfs list -plist >"$tmpxml"
    plutil -convert json -o "$tmpjson" "$tmpxml"
    jq -r '.Containers[].Volumes[] | select(.FileVault == true and .Locked == true) | .APFSVolumeUUID' "$tmpjson"
    rm -f "$tmpxml" "$tmpjson"
)
```

And, for convenience, you may want to put those commands into a shell function and call that instead (using `bash` here):

```
list_locked_vaults () {
    local tmpxml=$(mktemp)
    local tmpjson=$(mktemp)
    diskutil apfs list -plist >"$tmpxml"
    plutil -convert json -o "$tmpjson" "$tmpxml"
    jq -r '.Containers[].Volumes[] | select(.FileVault == true and .Locked == true) | .APFSVolumeUUID' "$tmpjson"
    rm -f "$tmpxml" "$tmpjson"
}

locked_uuids=$( list_locked_vaults )
```

Comment: 1line: `diskutil apfs list -plist | plutil -convert json -o - -`